# using pyspark how to reject bad (malformed) records from csv file and save these rejected records in a new file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark to load the data from csv file into a dataframe and I was able to load the data while dropping the malformed records but how can I reject these bad (malformed) records from the csv file and save these rejected records in a new file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL - loading csv/psv files with some malformed records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347448/spark-sql-loading-csv-psv-files-with-some-malformed-records)

Comment: It is not a duplicate as I need to reject the bad records into a new file (to identify these bad records) not to just drop the bad records

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think I might have an idea for this particular case. Could you post a couple of correct and malformed records?

Comment: Here is the sample data I work with :

Comment: 1,abcd,correct record1,description1
haha,efgh,Bad record,Bad record description
3,hijk,another correct record,description2

Comment: for the schema of the smaple data is :

schema = StructType([
    StructField("article_id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("title", StringType()),
    StructField("short_desc", StringType()),
    StructField("article_desc", StringType()),
StructField("Bad_Record", StringType())
])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea, although I am not very happy about it. The CSV parser has different modes, as you know, to drop malformed data. However, if no mode is specified, it 'fills the blanks' with a default `null` value. You can use that to your advantage.

Using this data, and assuming that the column `article_id` is not nullable by design:

```
1,abcd,correct record1,description1 haha
Bad record,Bad record description
3,hijk,another correct record,description2
Not_An_Integer,article,no integer type,description
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F

sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)

# Load the data with your schema, drop the malformed information
schema = StructType([ StructField("article_id", IntegerType()), 
                     StructField("title", StringType()), 
                     StructField("short_desc", StringType()), 
                     StructField("article_desc", StringType())]) 
valid_data = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").load("./data.csv")
valid_data.show()

"""
+----------+-----+--------------------+-----------------+
|article_id|title|          short_desc|     article_desc|
+----------+-----+--------------------+-----------------+
|         1| abcd|     correct record1|description1 haha|
|         3| hijk|another correct r...|     description2|
+----------+-----+--------------------+-----------------+
"""

# Load the data and let spark infer everything
malformed_data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load("./data.csv")
malformed_data.show()

"""
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|           _c0|                 _c1|                 _c2|              _c3|
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|             1|                abcd|     correct record1|description1 haha|
|    Bad record|Bad record descri...|                null|             null|
|             3|                hijk|another correct r...|     description2|
|Not_An_Integer|             article|     no integer type|      description|
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
"""

# Join and keep all data from the 'malformed' DataFrame.
merged = valid_data.join(malformed_data, on=valid_data.article_id == malformed_data._c0, how="right")

# Filter those records for which a matching with the 'valid' data was not possible
malformed = merged.where(F.isnull(merged.article_id))
malformed.show()

"""
+----------+-----+----------+------------+--------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+
|article_id|title|short_desc|article_desc|           _c0|                 _c1|            _c2|        _c3|
+----------+-----+----------+------------+--------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+
|      null| null|      null|        null|    Bad record|Bad record descri...|           null|       null|
|      null| null|      null|        null|Not_An_Integer|             article|no integer type|description|
+----------+-----+----------+------------+--------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+
"""
```

I am not too fond of this, as it is very sensitive to how Spark parses the CSV and it might not work for all files, but you might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would be very helpful

Comment: Very useful although a bit obscure :-) I requested such feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27593