# SPARK How to get column name in case of error (FAILFAST mode)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have the next code:

```
 spark.read()
               .schema(REPORT_OUTPUT_SCHEMA)
                .option("header", "true")
                 .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
                .csv(filePath)
                .show();
```

when i got the next error:

```
.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST. Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.00"
```

its not possible to determine in which column can be that error  when we have a big schema.

How usually find the needed column in that case?

Comment: Its not possible to determine the error  with out seeing original data

Comment: so what is usual way of hadnling such situatian . Using  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") ?

Comment: .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") either permissive or dropmalfomed you can use. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347448/spark-sql-loading-csv-psv-files-with-some-malformed-records)